# Debezium MYSQL Connector Timing out during initial snapshot

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, change-data-capture

We have deployed Debezium MYSQL Source connectors on Kafka Connect to stream data from MYSQL Tables. The connectors are working fine for very large tables (34 million records).

The issue is with this one table where inserts and updates happen every second and has approx. 20 million records. The Debezium connector is facing timeout issues during initial snapshot for this table. The number of records could not be the issue since we have successfully streamed data for larger tables but they were only getting updated in a 2 hour time window every day. The table for which we are facing issue updated every second (both inserts and updates happen). We tried to increase the snapshot.timeout.ms from 10000ms to 60000ms but that didn't resolve the issue.

Connector Config File:

```json
{
  "name": "DeviceUploadRecordSourceConnector_v1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "database.hostname": "hostname",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "username",
    "database.password": "${file:/etc/kcsecrets/hostname:username}",
    "database.server.name": "dbname",
    "time.precision.mode": "adaptive_time_microseconds",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka-servers",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.dbname",
    "column.include.list": "dbname.deviceuploadrecord.ID, dbname.deviceuploadrecord.SerialNum, dbname.deviceuploadrecord.UnProcessedFileSize, dbname.deviceuploadrecord.UnProcessedFilePath, dbname.deviceuploadrecord.ProcessedFileSize, dbname.deviceuploadrecord.FileHeaders, dbname.deviceuploadrecord.CreatedOn, dbname.deviceuploadrecord.ProcessedFilePath, dbname.deviceuploadmergerecord.ID, dbname.deviceuploadmergerecord.MergeFilePath, dbname.deviceuploadmergerecord.MergeFileSize, dbname.deviceuploadmergerecord.CreatedOn",
    "table.include.list": "dbname.deviceuploadrecord, dbname.deviceuploadmergerecord",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "snapshot.mode": "initial",
    "database.history.producer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
    "database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"{username}\" password=\"${file:/etc/kcsecrets/username:username}\";",
    "database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.location": "/volume/kafkaconnect/ssl/TrustStore.jks",
    "database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.password": "${file:/etc/kcsecrets/kafkatruststore:kafkatruststore}",
    "database.history.consumer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
    "database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"{username}\" password=\"${file:/etc/kcsecrets/username:username}\";",
    "database.history.consumer.ssl.truststore.location": "/volume/kafkaconnect/ssl/TrustStore.jks",
    "database.history.comsumer.ssl.truststore.password": "password"
  }
}
```

Exception Stack:

```json
{
  "name": "DeviceUploadRecordSourceConnector_v1",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "172.19.3.222:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "FAILED",
      "worker_id": "172.19.3.222:8083",
      "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:50)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:116)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:85)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.doSnapshot(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:155)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:137)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:109)\n\t... 5 more\nCaused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:123)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)\n\tat io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.executeWithoutCommitting(JdbcConnection.java:1446)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSnapshotChangeEventSource.tableLock(MySqlSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:450)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSnapshotChangeEventSource.readTableStructure(MySqlSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:314)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSnapshotChangeEventSource.readTableStructure(MySqlSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:46)\n\tat io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.doExecute(RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:116)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:76)\n\t... 8 more\n"
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debezium requires table lock during the initial snapshot. I expect that due to the inserts/updates the connector can not obtain a lock.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-snapshots

Few options could be to use replica with gtid or skip the initial snapshot.

Comment: Initially skipped the initial load when used snapshot.mode=schema_only but then talked to Gunnar, developer for Debezium and we used snapshot.locking.mode= none to include initial mode which worked, but need to make sure it is safe to use if and only if no schema changes are happening while the snapshot is running.